# Rails partial not rendering through ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to render a partial through ajax when a user clicks on button destroying a relationship between two products. The destroy action works, but I can not get the rendering of the partial to work.

The partial is rendered on the edit page for a product:

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div id="relationship_form">
  <%= render "relationships", product: @product %>
</div>
```

**_relationships.html.erb**

```
<%= render "unrelate", relationship: relationship %>
```

**_unrelate.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(relationship,html: { method: :delete },remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

**relationships_controller.html.erb**

```
def destroy
...
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_product_path }
  format.js
 end
end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#relationship_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'products/relationships', :locals => {:product => @product}) %>");
```

I have checked that the ajax call goes through to the destroy.js.erb, by inserting an alert, so there must be an error in the javascript?

**Update**:

I got it to work by moving the form in the _unrelate partial to the _relationship partial. Still not really clear why it made it work.

**_relationships.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(relationship,html: { method: :delete },remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is your code sample complete like this? It seems silly to render nothing but a partial in a partial. Regardless, here are a few tips as to how you can find out what the deal is:  (1) in chrome, use the inspector. (2) pay attention to ```rendered``` statements in the rails server log. (3) hit the url manually and observe the output, by typing localhost:3000/foo/bar.js in the address

Comment: Why do you pass `@product` as local variable to `relationships` partial while it expects `relationship` as a local variable?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.@voxobscuro I know, thinking about skipping the _unrelate partial...I will try the inspector now. @Ahmad Sherif: the ajax call goes from the unrelate partial, and a product has relationships. It works to remove the relationships, it is only that I want to re-render the partial instead of having to reload the page manually.

Comment: @voxobscuro: moved the second partial into the first one, and now it works...?

Comment: @graphmeter in your _relationships partial, you're passing on some variable relationship on to _unrelate...but I'm guessing you never set that.

Comment: @voxobscuro: relationship is set in the relationships partial, through a Relationship.where(...).each do |relationship|. Maybe not related, but I seem to get a routing error: `actionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products/53/edit/.json")`.

Comment: well, nothing here is set up to respond to json, so that could be another issue...but I also don't see anything here that would be requesting json from the server.

Comment: I think it is d3.js requesting the .json, maybe that is why I get this error.